# Int is not convertible to UIint32 error

Tags: ios, swift

i am new to swift and Xcode and i need some help. I have a function that gets to integer variables. And when i use them they give me errors. here is the code

`func checkTheNumber(range: Int, numberOfGuesses: Int) {
        var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range) + 1)
        numberOfGuesses--`

when i try to use the range variable it says "Int is not convertible to UIint32"
and when i try to use number of guesses it says "unary operator cannot be applied to an operand of type Int"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it with :

```
 var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range)) + 1)
```

You have to cast the `Int` to `UIint32`

Comment: @Volkodav what is it?

Comment: @Volkodav function parameters are immutable by default. the -- unary operator mutates the variable, which you cant do to an immutable variable. If you declare it as a var in the parameter list, you will be able to mutate it like `func checkTheNumber(range: Int, var numberOfGuesses: Int) {`